# Can a Java Compiler or JVM swap instruction order of independent instructions?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jvm, instructions

Let's take following statements:

```
int d0, d1;
int[] ds = {0, 0};
```

Now one thread has following instructions:

```
d0++;
d1++;
```

while the other thread has this instruction:

```
ds[1] = d1;
ds[0] = d0;
```

If we run these threads in parallel, there are obviously three combinations that `ds` can look like: {0, 0}, {1, 1}, and {1, 0}.

Now the big question is: Can there also be {0, 1}? Can the Compiler/JVM simply swap instruction because it thinks they are unrelated? If yes, what exactly are the "rules" for such behaviour and is it up to the compiler or the JVM?

Comment: Usually optimizations are considered safe if they behave the same as the unoptimized code in a serial (iow, one thread) model. Unless the relevant language constructs have explicit provisions for threading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `{0, 1}` is also possible.  The Java memory model is not strong enough to guarantee ordering in this case.  This doesn't even require instruction reordering -- this will happen anyway if you run the program on anything but x86 or x86_64.

To be clear here, the actual CPU hardware will reorder these loads and stores, just not if it's an x86.

See the [Java Memory Model FAQ](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#reordering)

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of proper synchronization, this is indeed possible.

The Java Language Specification defines the semantics of multi-threaded Java programs in chapter 17. That chapter is rather hard to understand, but it does contain the official rules one can rely on. In particular, it [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4):

> A memory model describes, given a program and an execution trace of that program, whether the execution trace is a legal execution of the program. The Java programming language memory model works by examining each read in an execution trace and checking that the write observed by that read is valid according to certain rules.
>
> The memory model describes possible behaviors of a program. An implementation is free to produce any code it likes, as long as all resulting executions of a program produce a result that can be predicted by the memory model.

To give a rough overview, the memory model defines a [happens-before relation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) any reorderings must be [consistent with](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.7). The usual way to establish happens-before for actions performed by different threads is to [synchronize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4) these actions, for instance with a `synchronized` block or writing to or reading from a volatile variable.

In the absence of such synchronization, the runtime will execute threads independently, permitting any reordering the *current* thread can not observe.

That is, if you have mutable shared state, you'll usually need to synchronize the threads accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes both compiler and jvm (just-in-time compiler) can do instruction reordering. Moreover, the hardware processor can do. To prevent unwanted reordering, [memory barriers](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#reordering)  should be used.